# Resizable sidebars in layout based on Holy Grail

Tags: css, layout

With [this layout](http://jsbin.com/zetubahe/1/edit) (not mine obviously), I want to resize/hide sidebars with javascript. Before writing the js code I tried to change the widths of right and left columns by hand. The problem is, when set to a smaller value, the center column does not fill up the released width. But the width of the main column is already set to 100%.

**So my question is**:

Given I want to reduce the width of the left column to 180px, what should I change to also have the main column fill up the blank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of layout uses padding to accommodate the side columns. So, if you want your left column to be 180px, with 10px of padding on each side, the main container needs to have a left padding of 200px (180px width + 10px padding * 2). As you change the width of the sidebars, you need to update the padding on the main container to match.

Comment: Right! Worked like a charm.